# Algoritmo Desligando Tela do PC após execução

Tags: c++, windows

Estou utilizando a windows.h em conjunto com C++, com a finalidade de criar uma rotina através dos eventos de INPUT. Tais como setar a posição do mouse na tela, clicar e coisas do gênero, porém toda vez que executo qualquer uma das duas funções, a tela apaga em seguida (Como se tivesse ficado ausente por muito tempo), pois basta movimentar o mouse que ela volta.

```
void setMousePos(int posX, int posY){
    INPUT Input;
    Input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
    Input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE;

    Input.mi.dx = posX*(65535.0f/GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN));
    Input.mi.dy = posY*(65535.0f/GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN));
    SendInput(true,&Input, sizeof(Input));
}

void onClick(){
    INPUT Input;
    Input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;
    SendInput(true, &Input, sizeof(Input));
    Input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;
    SendInput(true, &Input, sizeof(Input));
}
```

Ele simplesmente executa as funções, e em seguida, apaga a tela. Alguma do Por Que está ocorrendo o mesmo?

O Problema está na multiplicação pelo resultado da divisão `65535.0f/GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);`

Se eu executo a conta com um numero normal (1280 por exemplo), ocorre tudo bem, porém quando utilizo uma variável (posX por exemplo), ele é a causa do apagão.

- Sistema Operacional: **Windows 8.1**
- Linguagem: **C++**
- Biblioteca: **windows.h**

Comment: Descobri que na realidade, o problema não é a divisão, e sim a multiplicação feita após obter o resultado da divisão. Porém, se eu executo a conta com números normais, não há problema algum, exemplo: Input.mi.dy = 800*(65535.0f/GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN));. Porém se no lugar do 800 eu utilizar uma variável, isto causará o apagão.

Comment: Resolvi o problema por enquanto. Ao invés de criar um INPUT toda vez que executasse a função, coloquei-o para passar como argumento: void setMousePos(int posX, int posY, INPUT& Input). Desta forma inicializo o mesmo na função main.

Comment: Você pode zerar a estrutura toda, ao criar o INPUT. o importante é, por exemplo, como vc nao usa o x e o y no click, zere eles na função click. Os membros que vc nao usar no move, zere na função de mover, e assim por diante. Mais fácil é você zerar a estrutura toda ao criar o input, o que é relativamente simples. Isso não vale só pra esse caso. Sempre que usar uma estrutura desse tipo, tenha a certeza de ter ela limpa;

Comment: Olá, fico feliz que você tenha corrigido o problema. Mas, sendo assim, por favor crie você mesmo uma resposta detalhando a sua solução (e a marque como aceita). **Não edite a pergunta para incluir a solução**, poir esse site não é um fórum. Se não fez ainda, por favor leia a [help]. :)

Comment: Quase você criou o seu primeiro vírus, já pode mandar pro seus amigos pra perturbar eles :) - Brincadeiras a parte, que bom que conseguiu resolver, recomendo que poste a função "inteira" como ficou.

Answer (score 3):

Problema Resolvido. E agradecimentos à Luiz Vieira por ter me orientado, e a Bacco por ter me ajudado.
A solução foi ao iniciar o INPUT, seta-lo como 0:

```
setMousePos(int posX, int posY){
    INPUT Input={0} // A resolução do problema foi simples assim
    .......... /Resto do Código
}
```